# gVim 7.4 and snipMate on windows

Tags: vim, snipmate

Spent some time installing snipMate in gVim 7.4 on Windows.
I used Vundle to install the dependencies.

`Bundle "MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils"
Bundle "tomtom/tlib_vim"
Bundle "garbas/vim-snipmate"
Bundle "honza/vim-snippets"`

I loaded a new file `test.c`

When I do `for<TAB>` the snippet is working, I see this:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

}
```

When I exit the file and open it again and type `for<TAB>` I get this error message:

```
error detected while processing ..\bundle\vim-snipmate\autoload\snipMate.vim
you're missing tlib...
```

Now when I do `:BundleInstall` after opening a file it is working again.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Currently I have solved it by installing snipMate using Pathogen and it is working fine. But still would like to know how to fix having to do `:BundleInstall` every time using Vundle.